# C# - HTML and CSS (With WinForms/WPF?)

Tags: c#, html, css

I understand that this may not be possible, but is there anyway to make a HTML and CSS UI with a C# Backend? I much prefer CSS with UI.

**Also I need it to be runnable as a .exe, not from a server or something**

Comment: Yes, use Webforms. 

https://www.asp.net/web-forms

Comment: Did you mean, use HTML tag and CSS file in winform/WPF?

Comment: Embedd a WebBrowser, use it as interface, attach to DOM events and interact with it.

Comment: @John is webforms secure and have all of the features from WinForms?

Comment: @Ariwibawa Yes or some kind of Wrapper/API method that will allow it.

Comment: @Gusman can you explain that in more detail and how I can achieve a simple Hello World MessageBox from a Button?

Comment: I looked into ASP.Net, It seems to be a form of replacing JS for C# for Websites which isnt what im looking for.

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/990346/Using-HTML-as-UI-Elements-in-a-WinForms-Applicatio

Answer (score 2):

I'm the maintainer of NanUI project. NanUI is an open source component for .NET / .NET Core Windows Form Applications. It's base on Chromium Embedded Framework. So you can use HTML5, CSS3 and JavaScript to create desktop applications.

[Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqyYT.png)

All resources can be embedded in Assembly so you don't need a webserver to host the webpages.

You can pull and try it.

https://github.com/NetDimension/NanUI

Comment: I'm trying about two days to figure out how to use the NanUI library. How can I setup a very basic Application that uses html/css/javascript as embedded resources?

Comment: Sorry for my poor English, I can not explain how to do this clearly in English. There is an example video that will tell you how to use embedded files in assembly, but it is a Chinese version. You can follow the steps in this video without listening. https://m.bilibili.com/video/BV1Xz4y167FP